# ruby return fixed number of elements in a certain order

Tags: ruby

This might be a dumb question.
I know sample returns random number of elements from an array.
For example,
[1,2,3].sample.times do

Is there a way to return a fixed number of  elements in a certain order always?
I dont know how to do this in ruby.

EDIT:
Lets say I always want to return penalty_name, severity and name only from the second and last array here always.:

```
offenses = PERSON_SUMMARY[:offenses].map do |offense|
  offense[:penalties].map do |penalty|
    penalty.merge(name: offense[:offense_name])
  end
end.flatten

=> [{:penalty_name=>"Prison", :severity=>"Medium", :name=>"Speeding"}, {:penalty_name=>"Ticket", :severity=>"Low", :name=>"Speeding"}, {:penalty_name=>"Prison", :severity=>"Medium", :name=>"Shoplifting"}, {:penalty_name=>"Fine", :severity=>"Low", :name=>"Shoplifting"}]
```

right now I am doing:

```
offenses.each do |hash|
hash.sample
```

Comment: How would you know which elements to return?  Can you define the problem more precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].sample(4).sort
```

It will take 4 random number from the array and order it...

**edit** - after your comment:

```
[5,4,3,2,1].values_at(1,-1).sort #second element(1) and last one(-1)
=>[1, 4]
```

Comment: thanks.but i dont want random elements. everytime it should return me the same elements that i require

Comment: sample will always return random elements

Comment: if you want to specify the elements you can use `values_at` and than sort it... I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which ones you want with `values_at` (negative numbers count from the back.)

```
ar=[{:penalty_name=>"Prison", :severity=>"Medium", :name=>"Speeding"}, {:penalty_name=>"Ticket", :severity=>"Low", :name=>"Speeding"}, {:penalty_name=>"Prison", :severity=>"Medium", :name=>"Shoplifting"}, {:penalty_name=>"Fine", :severity=>"Low", :name=>"Shoplifting"}]
p ar.values_at(1,-1).map{|h|h.values}
#=> [["Ticket", "Low", "Speeding"], ["Fine", "Low", "Shoplifting"]]
```